# S3 bucket policy preventing boto from setting cache headers

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I've developed a Python script using the `boto` library to upload files to my S3 bucket. When uploading the file using the `Key.set_contents_from_filename` method, I specify the `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers to enable proper browser caching. This all works fine, the files appear in my bucket with the correct headers set in the metadata field.

To prevent hotlinking of my files, I added the following bucket policy in S3:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "MySite",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Deny access if not specified referrer",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://www.mysite.com/*",
                        "http://mysite.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy works to prevent hotlinking, but now when I upload files using boto, the `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers are not being set. Removing the bucket policy fixes the problem, so I'm clearly not specifying the bucket policy properly.

Any ideas on how to modify my bucket policy to allow uploading metadata fields with boto while still preventing hotlinking?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the headers myself. But maybe the problem is with Referer header. I suggest you add this policy that allows get and put object to your bucket using Referer.

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowFromReferer",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::745684876799:user/IAM_USER"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "http://mysite.com/*",
                    "http://www.mysite.com/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

If this fails, you can assume the problem is with Referer. Use just * for referer and if it works fine, then it definitely is your Referer problem.